# opening a text file using process.start

Tags: c#

i've been trying to open a text file from my system after computing pearson correlation and writing the result on a text file but so far for some reason the code doesn't open any notepad files i've tried opening other files and they work fine but .txt files are not opening specifically, even .docx files are opening using the same code! if anyone could please tell me if there is any specific reason for this! here is the line i'm writing in my code using process.start()

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Atif\Desktop\1.txt");
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"\\1.txt");
```

i think there's something wrong with my PC i just tried the same code on another machine and it is working! but i still don't understand what could be the problem apart from this program the notepad is working fine!

Comment: Have you set default program for opening txt files as notepad? just my assumption it can be the reason. not sure.

Comment: What happens if you try it from the command line? (i.e. type something like `start C:\Users\Atif\Desktop\1.txt`) If that doesn't work, then it won't work using `Process.Start()` either.

Answer (score 8):

if you want to use Notepad to open the file and it is not the default text editor you can use like following:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"C:\Users\Atif\Desktop\1.txt");
```

Comment: yes i've been trying this overloaded function as well but still it doesn't work! all the other types of files are opening just fine!

Comment: Does notepad open when you double click the file?

Comment: What about trying the full path to notepad and just trying to start it without your file?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe");

Comment: you mean this!? it still doesn't open notepad! :(

Comment: i think there's something wrong with my PC i just tried the same code on another machine and it is working! but i still don't understand what could be the problem apart from this program the notepad is working fine!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I had a similar issue with .Net 7.0 (worked in .Net 4.8.1)...
I had to use:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(Filename);
psi.Verb = "open";
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with type association. Right click on .txt file, select Open With, choose Notepad and check "Always use..." checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

First what debug error are you getting?

I was having a similar issue and the problem was my extension was "file.txt.txt"

To avoid this (Windows 10) turn off "Hide extensions for known file types":
If File explorer -  View > options > change folder and search options > view > (Un-tick) Hide extensions for known file types > Apply.

[Showing how to show file extensions for known file types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh544.png)