# C# - Process.Start()

Tags: c#, process.start

I want to open test.txt. In the previous project, I opened it with code below, but in the new project, nothing happened. I tried many other solutions but nothing...

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
     string path = @"C:\\Users\\SB-Darjan\\Desktop\\Loader\\MG30\\MG30\\test.txt";
     Process.Start(path);
}
```

Comment: Don't double up your backslashes in a verbatim string. Pick one or the other: verbatim string or double backslashes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opening a text file using process.start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583816/opening-a-text-file-using-process-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use @ symbol with path then you should use single backslash.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    string path = @"C:\Users\SB- 
    Darjan\Desktop\Loader\MG30\MG30\test.txt"; 
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", path); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even with single is not working...

Comment: Do you have access to that path?

Comment: Is this file test.txt exists in the specified path?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can use the same instruction but adding the exe you want to use to open your file as shown below .

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"C:\Users\SB-Darjan\Desktop\Loader\MG30\MG30\test.txt");
```